# fill values ONLY BETWEEN rows in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a project with some pricing data for second hand cars, due to the nature of the data there are gaps in the dataframe I am working with.

I need to fill the gaps in the columns, but only if they are BETWEEN two values (i.e. there are values both above the `Nan`).

Here is a simplified example of what I am working with:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

date_index = pd.date_range(datetime(2023,2,1), datetime(2023,2,8))

prices_dict = {
    
    'car1': [1000, 1000, np.nan, np.nan, 1200, 1250, np.nan, np.nan],
    'car2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 500, 600, 610, 630, np.nan],
    'car3': [np.nan, 1000, np.nan, 950, np.nan, 950, np.nan, np.nan],
    'car4': [np.nan, 790, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 800, 750, 750],
}

prices_df = pd.DataFrame(data=prices_dict, index=date_index)
```

It looks like this:

```
--------    car1    car2    car3    car4
2023-02-01  1000.0          
2023-02-02  1000.0         1000.0   790.0
2023-02-03              
2023-02-04          500.0   950.0   
2023-02-05  1200.0  600.0       
2023-02-06  1250.0  610.0   950.0   800.0
2023-02-07          630.0           750.0
2023-02-08                          750.0
```

I have done some digging and know of the existence of `.ffil()` `.bfill()` and `.fillna()` but these seem to be uniquely forward or backwards filling. I need to fill forwards but only for blanks between two values.

The expected outcome is

```
--------    car1    car2    car3    car4
2023-02-01  1000.0          
2023-02-02  1000.0         1000.0   790.0
2023-02-03  1000.0         1000.0   790.0
2023-02-04  1000.0  500.0   950.0   790.0
2023-02-05  1200.0  600.0   950.0   790.0
2023-02-06  1250.0  610.0   950.0   800.0
2023-02-07          630.0           750.0
2023-02-08                          750.0
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two alternative ways:

```
df.ffill().where(df.ffill().notna() & df.bfill().notna())
```

or

```
df.ffill().where(df.iloc[::-1].notna().cummax())
```

Output:

```
              car1   car2    car3   car4
2023-02-01  1000.0    NaN     NaN    NaN
2023-02-02  1000.0    NaN  1000.0  790.0
2023-02-03  1000.0    NaN  1000.0  790.0
2023-02-04  1000.0  500.0   950.0  790.0
2023-02-05  1200.0  600.0   950.0  790.0
2023-02-06  1250.0  610.0   950.0  800.0
2023-02-07     NaN  630.0     NaN  750.0
2023-02-08     NaN    NaN     NaN  750.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with right parameters:

```
>>> prices_df.interpolate(method='pad', limit_area='inside', axis=1)
              car1   car2    car3   car4
2023-02-01  1000.0    NaN     NaN    NaN
2023-02-02  1000.0    NaN  1000.0  790.0
2023-02-03  1000.0    NaN  1000.0  790.0
2023-02-04  1000.0  500.0   950.0  790.0
2023-02-05  1200.0  600.0   950.0  790.0
2023-02-06  1250.0  610.0   950.0  800.0
2023-02-07     NaN  630.0     NaN  750.0
2023-02-08     NaN    NaN     NaN  750.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Did not realise you could pass a 'limit_area' inside .interpolate()